# Multiple Rows into single row column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of SQL data results which outline my "Off-Peak Hours" for each day.  I need to get this off peak hour data into a single text line that explains the hours available.

e.g. "8:30am - 11:30am & 2pm - 5:30pm on weekdays and 10:00am - 5:30pm on weekends"

below is an example of my returned data set:

```html
DayOfWeek StartTime         EndTime
1         08:30:00.0000000 11:30:00.0000000
2         08:30:00.0000000 11:30:00.0000000
3         08:30:00.0000000 11:30:00.0000000
4         08:30:00.0000000 11:30:00.0000000
5         08:30:00.0000000 11:30:00.0000000
6         10:00:00.0000000 17:30:00.0000000
1         14:00:00.0000000 17:30:00.0000000
2         14:00:00.0000000 17:30:00.0000000
3         14:00:00.0000000 17:30:00.0000000
4         14:00:00.0000000 17:30:00.0000000
5         14:00:00.0000000 17:30:00.0000000
7         10:00:00.0000000 17:30:00.0000000
```

I have never written any SQL that comes close to thinking how you could do this...Some guidance would be really helpful in learning how to do this kind of complex SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CASE statement to group weekdays/weekends.  Then just distinct it.

```
 SELECT distinct
   CASE WHEN DayOfWeek in (1,7) THEN 'weekend' ELSE 'weekday' END as dow
   ,starttime, endtime
    FROM table
```

Seeing as you want it on one line though, we force a pivot.

```
SELECT
   min(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek in (1,7) THEN starttime END) as start_wknd
   ,min(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek in (1,7) THEN endtime END) as end_wknd
   ,min(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek not in (1,7) THEN starttime END) as start_wkday
   ,min(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek not in (1,7) THEN endtime END) as end_wkday
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way is to do a self join of the table to itself.
The issue with your table is that there is nothing to identify the first,
second, or third occurrence of the day of the week.  To get this, you
need to add a Rank() column.  Perhaps making a temporary table would make this look cleaner.  Some SQL languages let you use a "Using" clause to define this temporary table for only this query.

Here is a rough version

```
Using TMP_TABLE as (select DayOfWeek, StartTime,EndTime,rank() order by 
StartTime partition by dayofweek as Rnk )
select
A.DayOfWeek, A.StartTime, A.EndTime,
        B.StartTime, B.EndTime,
        C.StartTime, C.EndTime
from TMP_TABLE A
inner join TMP_TABLE B on A.DayOfWeek = B.DayOfWeek
inner join TMP_TABLE C on A.Dayofweek = C.DayOfWeek
where 
A.Rnk = 1
and B.Rnk = 2
and C.Rnk = 3
;
```

If you cannot use "Using" then repeat the subquery with rank in every place where TMP_TABLE appears.